# Regex to detect numbers only between special characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need Regex to detect numbers only between special characters.

Pattern  `;\d+=\d+?`

String `0014;5010730101000033347=4510120173?AA`

My objective is to get this string

```
;5010730101000033347=4510120173?
```

Comment: Can you be more precise what your special characters are?

Comment: @vitaly-t They are   ; = ?

Comment: You miss a single backslash . `@";\d+=\d+\?` .....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\d+?` at the end of the pattern matches 1 digit, no more, due to the `+?` *lazy quantifier* matching 1 or more occurrences, but *as few as necessary to return a valid match*.

You may use

```
;\d+=\d+\?
        ^^
```

C# declaration:

```
string pattern = @";\d+=\d+\?";
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3b%5cd%2b%3d%5cd%2b%5c%3f&i=0014%3b5010730101000033347%3d4510120173%3fAA)

**Details**:

- `;` - a semi-colon
- `\d+`  - 1 or more digits
- `=` - an equal sign
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\?` - **a literal `?` char**

[image]